# Correctly set numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an app that load data using `AFNetworking`, parsing income JSON data and populate table. I use different class to manage JSON and to populate `UITableView`.

I need to correctly set number of rows. Problem is, i guess its method load too early, before we get any data from web. I tried following:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfElements{


return [self.dataDictArray count];
```

}

And then:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.handler numberOfElements];
}
```

When handler is an instance type of class, that deal with JSON and declare `-(NSInteger)numberOfElements`.

How can i set correct number of elements in such situation? Apparently `tableView` load **before** we got web data, that's kind of confusing.

Comment: You could do `[tableView reloadData]` after the `self.handler` finished loading the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is:

In success block of AFNetworking get method fire a notification

```
  #define NOTIFICATION_NAME @"LoadNotification"  

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_NAME object:self];
```

In viewDidLoad method of UITableViewController subclass set the class as observer of notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedLoadingNotification:) name:NOTIFICATION_NAME object:nil];
```

In 'receivedLoadingNotification' method set the delegate and datasourceDelegate

```
-(void)receivedLoadingNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:NOTIFICATION_NAME])
    {
        [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
        [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    }
}
```

So, the controller will only call the dataSource and delegate methods when JSON data is successfully loaded from AFNetworking.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try but it look like a bit weird ))

Comment: I also dealt with this situation in this way only, may be weird but would work definitely.

Comment: Yeah i guess it will work, i just want to mention that i never seen that approach. But i can't figure out better solution by myself, so i'll try, thanks!

Comment: what is receivedLoadingNotification? Did you declare this somewhere?

Comment: Yes I mentioned it in the answer as the 'selector' method to be called when table viewController recieved notification.

Comment: Apparently that solution not work for me, because i did loading routine in cellForRowAtIndexPath, therefore, its not calling, because its UITableViewDelegate method.. i really don't want to call that method 2 times but look like i forced to..

Comment: Why you are calling it two times, instad of setting delegate and datasourceDelegate property in viewDidLoad of uiTableView just set in  'receivedLoadingNotification' method.

Comment: Because i declare AFNetworking download method in cellForRowAtIndexPath, which is UITableView delegate method. Its not called, therefore no notification given.

Comment: BUT why are you calling it in cellForRowAtIndexPath , hows that logically possible that numberofRows you dont know prior and in cellForRowAtIndexPath you are actually knowing the numberOfRows.

Comment: you should call the AFNetworking method in viewDidLoad .

Comment: It's easier, yes, but it mess up your code and goes against basic design patterns. However, i finding solution using your advice, i will edit my post when I'm done. Thanks